# In Sequelize, the options.foreignkey on the association methods refers to a database attribute/field or to a model property?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I checked the documentation and it describes `[options.foreignKey]` as follows:

> The name of the foreign key in the source table or an object representing the type definition for the foreign column (see  Sequelize.define for syntax). When using an object, you can add a name property to set the name of the column. Defaults to the name of target + primary key of target

So, I'm not sure if I should be specifying a database attribute/field or to a model property.

I have the following model definition:

```
let attributes = {
    // ...
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        references: {
            model: 'User',
            key: 'id'
        },
        field: 'Usuario_id'
    }
    // ...
};

let options = {
    tableName: 'Colaborador',
    timestamps: false,
    classMethods: {
        associate: (models) => {
            Collaborator.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
        }
    }
};

let Collaborator = sequelize.define('Collaborator', attributes, options);
```

Therefore, which of the options below should be used?

```
Collaborator.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
```

Or

```
Collaborator.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'Usuario_id' });
```